# How to install a library wheel during package installation (via pyproject.toml or setyp.py)?

Tags: python, setup.py, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

I have a package build into a .whl that needs some libraries to be installed prior to the package installation.
Their presence are checked within the `pyproject.toml` and its dependencies section:

```
dependencies = [
     'numpy',
     'pandas',
     ...
]
```

However, if one of the required libraries is not already installed on the computer, the package installation process is stopped.

In my case I have libraries that need a wheel to be installed (can not be found by pip directly as user-made libraries) and in order to avoid the user having to deal with their installation, I would like to have the library wheel installation part of the package wheel installation.

To give an example, my user-made library wheel `library.whl` is within a dedicated folder and will be part of the package installation when doing `python pip install example.whl`:

```
/path_to_example_package/
    ├── example/          (Package directory)
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── example_module.py
    ├── data/          (Folder containing the missing libraries)
    │   └── library.whl
    ├── pyproject.toml
    ├── README.md
    └── setup.py
```

I have tried to add the library wheel path within `pyproject.toml` dependencies but not working (or wrong syntax). Maybe with the `setup.py` or may be it is not possible.
Any thought?

Many thanks for your help on this topic.

Comment: Short answer not possible. Packaging metadata is for abstract dependencies only. You want to have concrete dependencies in the packaging metadata and it is not possible. [This document](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/) needs an update but the message is still the same. -- What you need to do is provide good documentation explaining that this one particular wheel must be installed as a dependency.