# How to include a whl file in a Python package and install it as a dependency (in pyproject.toml)

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I am creating a Python package and in my requirements I have a certain (hardware-related) Python package that is not available in PyPI or Git or anywhere else on the web. I would like to include this file in the package so that it gets installed when i run `pip install my-package` or `pip install --editable .` from the package directory.

How to I package and install a "local" dependency with setuptools and pyproject.toml?

I have placed the .whl (actually a .zip-file, but it seems to install fine with pip) in a folder called `libs/` under the root. In `requirements.txt` I can just write `./libs/package_name.whl` and it works when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. However, I cannot figure out a way to do the same with `pyproject.toml`. Currently I have tried:

```
[project]
dependencies = [
    ...
    "package_name @ file:///libs/package_name.whl"
```

This does not work, as relative file paths are not allowed. How should an absolute file path even work, if this could be run at the end-users computer?

I am quite confused (and frustrated) about how this case should be handled. I have seen other asking the same or similar questions (eg. [How to install a library wheel during package installation (via pyproject.toml or setyp.py)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067551/how-to-install-a-library-wheel-during-package-installation-via-pyproject-toml-o)). None of these questions seem to have satisfying answers (like suggesting to host the external package myself) and so far I have not figured out an alternative strategy.

Comment: Depending on how your own package is supposed to be available, perhaps the most natural solution is to make the other wheel available through the same channel. For example, if you intend for your package to be available through a private package repository, the other package could live there as well.

Comment: For me, there are two major downsides to that workaround. First, if the intended distribution method is not an online platform, then we are back at defining absolute paths to whl files - or alternatively a multi-step installation process. The second problem is that I believe this workaround would require to hard-code the distribution location to the dependency requirement, which would break if it ever changes. Ultimately, this it feels like a "hack" for something that should be obvious and trivial to do.

Comment: For anyone trying to find a solution to this, it seems that this behaviour is by design. This [blog post](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/) describes the effects and the [Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/) outlines the differences between requirements.txt and install_requires. I am still searching for a solution to make a package installable when it depends on a non-publicly available dependency. Preferably I would like to find a way to "hint" where to find the concrete dependency in pyproject.toml.